# Adding more waypoints to GPX file?

Tags: gpx

I have some GPX data for flights I've taken, but the waypoints are very intermittent - often times 100's of km apart.  I have an app called Fog of the World which I use as a hobby to track the places I've been.  It allows me to import GPX data, but will not create a line when there is more than 5km between waypoints.  Most GPX visualizers will create this line regardless.  I was wondering if there was an easy way to add extra waypoints between the existing way points (that follow the lines) to satisfy the needs of the app.  I've tried the hand drawing tools on some websites, but obviously that's such a tedious way to map out these flights.

Comment: If your are handy at python here is a gpx manipulator https://github.com/tkrajina/gpxpy

Comment: may be https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133026/great-circles-in-qgis-and-export-in-3857-webmap would help

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the interpolation function on GPSPRUNE helps you out!?

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange! As a new user be sure to [take the tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Please elaborate on your answer (example of how to use this function, links to its documentation, why you think it might be helpful etc.) Single line answers without context may not be of help to the original poster or those who find this thread in the future.